# MYSQL - get the most recent result when using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have the following tables on my MYSQL database:

`USERS`

```
ID | login
---------------
1  | user1
2  | user2
3  | user3
```

`STATUS`

```
ID | userID    | date                | status
1  | 1         | 2018-05-10 10:00:00 | a
2  | 2         | 2018-05-15 10:00:00 | a
3  | 3         | 2018-05-20 10:00:00 | a
4  | 3         | 2018-05-20 11:00:00 | d
5  | 1         | 2018-05-15 11:00:00 | d
6  | 3         | 2018-05-25 10:00:00 | a
```

How do I query the `STATUS` table to get only the rows with the most recent `date` and where the column `status` is equal to `a` with no repeated `userID`?

These are the lines that I want my query to return in this case:

```
userID    | date                | status
2         | 2018-05-15 10:00:00 | a
3         | 2018-05-25 10:00:00 | a
```

Comment: @Shadow, my question is not at all the same as this one you suggested

Answer (score 0):

you could try the below:

```
select s1.userID, s1.date, s1.status from status s1
inner join (select userID, max(date) date from status group by userID) s2 
  on s2.date = s1.date and s1.userID = s2.userID
where s1.status = 'a';
```

Above I create a table that has the `max(date)` per `UserID`.  We can join this table back to the raw table, using `inner join` we ensure results are only latest date rows.  We use a `where` clause to filter the output for only those rows with `Status = 'a'`

You can play with the query in SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ddf1b/14/0)

Comment: Thanks for answering. This query you suggested will also bring as a result the row with the userID equals to 1 and I don't want that since I've changed its status to d.

Comment: @BrunoCosta thanks for clarifying.  Please see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can ma nage as you want `INTEVRAL n DAY` regarding how many days back you wanna check.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM STATUS WHERE STATUS.date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but that is not at all what I wanted